# Sorting Results by time in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to get some time series data from Cassandra

My table is presented on picture , and when I query,  I'm getting data as presented next:
first I'm seeing all false data regardless of time when I inserted them in Cassandra, and next I'm seeing all true data. 
My question is: how can I sort or roder data by time when I inserted, consistently, in order to I'm be able to get data in order when I insert them.

When I try "select c1 from table1 order by c2", I get the following error "ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN."

Thank you
[My boolean table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS7GE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your schema is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
c1,
c2,
PRIMARY KEY (c1))
```

This will result in 2 partitions in your table (c1 = true and c1=false). Each partition will be managed by a single node.

Your initial query will retrieve data from your table across all partitions. So it will go to the first partition, retrieve all the rows then the second and retrieve all the rows, which is why you're seeing the results you do.

Cassandra is optimised for retrieving data across one partition only, so you should look at adjusting your schema to allow that - to use ORDER BY in the query, you need to be retrieving data across one partition only.

Depending on your use case, you could look at bucketing your data or performing the sorting in your application.

Comment: Alec thank you for your answer. In my table c1 is the boolean value and c2 is the timestamp. But I think I've found the solution